# Problem updating the height of my timeline in a dynamic react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a Timeline component that I've implemented twice on my page. In this component I have a "timeline" div whose height increases with scroll to reach the bottom of its container. It works fine when I scroll in the 1st component, but when I get to the second the height of the "timeline" div is already at 100%.

Here's my code:

```
const DesktopProcess = ({ datas }) => {
  const phase1 = datas?.phases[0];
  const phase2 = datas?.phases[1];
  return (
    <>
      <div className="dekstop-view-regul-white">{parse(datas?.teaser)}</div>;
      <div className="dekstop-view-regul-no-bg">
        <Title
          textColor={"black"}
          dateBg={"#0aa2a5"}
          title={phase1?.title}
          durea={phase1?.durea}
          dateTextColor={"white"}
          addMargin={""}
        />
        <TimeLine
          lengthLine={phase1?.datas?.length}
          datas={phase1?.datas}
          bgBubble={""}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="dekstop-view-regul-green">
        <Title
          textColor={"#14b5bf"}
          dateBg={"black"}
          title={phase2?.title}
          durea={phase2?.durea}
          dateTextColor={"white"}
          addMargin={"add-margin-b-title"}
        />
        <TimeLine
          lengthLine={phase2?.datas?.length}
          datas={phase2?.datas}
          bgBubble={"bubble-green"}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const TimeLine = ({ lengthLine, datas, bgBubble }) => {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  const [endReached, setEndReached] = useState(false);
  const timelineRef = useRef(null);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (timelineRef.current && !endReached) {
      // Continuez à ajuster seulement si la fin n'est pas encore atteinte
      const position = window.pageYOffset - timelineRef.current.offsetTop;
      setScrollPosition(position + 50);
      console.log("height:", scrollPosition);
      console.log("ref:", timelineRef.current);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, [timelineRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (endReached) {
      setScrollPosition(0);
    }
  }, [endReached]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        const entry = entries[0];
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          setEndReached(true); // L'élément de fin est visible, fixez la hauteur de la timeline
        }
      },
      {
        root: null, // surveille l'intersection par rapport au viewport
        threshold: 0.1, // déclenche lorsque 10% de l'élément observé est visible
      }
    );

    const endElement = document.querySelector(".end");
    if (endElement) {
      observer.observe(endElement);
    }

    return () => {
      if (endElement) {
        observer.unobserve(endElement); // Nettoyage
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const bubbles = Array.from({ length: lengthLine }, (_, index) => (
    <Bubble key={index} index={index} bgBubble={bgBubble} />
  ));

  return (
    <div className="time-line-container" ref={timelineRef}>
      <span className="start"></span>
      {bubbles}
      <div
        className="timeline"
        style={{ height: endReached ? "100%" : `${scrollPosition}px` }}
      ></div>
      <div className="container-steps-time-line">
        {datas &&
          datas?.map((i, index) => {
            return <Steps datas={i} key={index} index={index} />;
          })}
      </div>
      <span className="end"></span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thank you for your help